# how to append csrf_field() in laravel pagination link?

Tags: laravel

How to append the csrf_field() to links in laravel pagination. I am trying the following code but not working.

```
{{$search_results->appends(['_token' =>csrf_field()])->links()}}
```

Comment: you don't need the CSRF token ... The token is not checked on GET requests

Comment: I want to use csrf for filtering spam submission on search results

Comment: you can use `csrf_token()`

Comment: not working in appends

Comment: `csrf_field()` will give you a output like this, `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="7YC0Sxth7AYe4RFSjzaPf2ygLCecJhblahblah">` you need the token, so use `csrf_token()` instead, it will give you a output like `7YC0Sxth7AYe4RFSjzaPf2ygLCecJhPbyXhz6vvF`